# Change service startup type to Delayed (Automatic) in remote machine

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am using the below code to change the service start in a remote server up type to manual/automatic using C#.

```
public static void ChangeServiceStartupType()
    {

        string query1 = "select * from Win32_Service where name = 'myservice' ";


        string server = "servername";
        ConnectionOptions connectoptions = new ConnectionOptions();

        connectoptions.Username = @"username";
        connectoptions.Password = "password";

        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\" + server + @"\root\cimv2");
        scope.Options = connectoptions;
        scope.Connect();

        ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery(query1);
        ManagementObjectSearcher managementObjectSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
        ManagementObjectCollection managementObjectCollection = managementObjectSearcher.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject mo in managementObjectSearcher.Get())
        {
            string name = mo.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString().Trim().ToLower();
            string state = mo.Properties["State"].Value.ToString().Trim();
            string startmode = mo.Properties["StartMode"].Value.ToString().Trim();
            changemode(mo, "Automatic");
        }
    }
```

Here is the changemode method

```
private static void changemode(ManagementObject mo, string startmode)
    {
        ManagementBaseObject inParams = mo.GetMethodParameters("ChangeStartMode");
        inParams["startmode"] = startmode;
        ManagementBaseObject outParams = mo.InvokeMethod("ChangeStartMode", inParams, null);
        startmode = mo.Properties["StartMode"].Value.ToString().Trim();
    }
```

When I pass the parameters **Manual** or **Automatic** in the changemode(object,**startmode parameter**) the service start up type changes from automatic to manual and vice-versa. However, I am unable to change it to Automatic(Delayed Start).

I tried **Auto-Delayed** , **Delayed-Auto**, **Automatic (Delayed Start)** How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If there's a way through ManagementObject than I haven't found it, but it IS possible through the registry:

```
public void SetDalayedAutoStart(string machineName, string serviceName)
{
    using (var regKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, machineName))
    {
        using (RegistryKey serviceKey = regKey.OpenSubKey(@"System\CurrentControlSet\Services\" + serviceName, true))
        {
            serviceKey.SetValue("DelayedAutostart", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note 1**: This is only relevant for services with the Automatic start type

**Note 2**: The new state will be visible in the Services control (services.msc) only after a restart (don't ask me why)

Comment: You can enhance the ServiceController class by making this an extension method (assuming you've the permissions to access the remote service)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384896(v=vs.85).aspx), it doesn't seem to be possible to make the service start with a delay using the `ChangeStartMode` Win32 method. Doing what you want is fairly straightforward if you use `ServiceInstaller`, like so:

```
myServiceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
myServiceInstaller.DelayedAutoStart = true;
```

However I'm guessing that isn't an option, so we will have to dig deeper.

The [Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418(v=vs.85).aspx) class does have a `DelayedAutoStart` property, but it is read only. If you want to set it to delayed, you're going to have to mess around with P/Invokes. All information I could find points to [ChangeServiceConfig2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681988(VS.85).aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685155(v=vs.85).aspx) struct.

Alternatively, you can just execute this command it it will have the same effect. However, it isn't really an answer to your question, just a workaround.

```
sc.exe config myService start= delayed-auto
```

Finally, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32589671/7662085) (very) long answer by user [Kramii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11514/kramii), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5742574/7662085) by [Peter Kelly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215600/peter-kelly). Both of them wrote helper classes to make doing this sort of thing a lot easier. I haven't tested them but they look promising.

Comment: thanks @Sty for your inputs. I figured out a way to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Sty's answer lets you set a service to automatic delayed at the time of creation; not post deployment.

There is a command line that can do that

```
sc \\computername config *servicename* start= delayed-auto
```

I ran this command line in the remote server using WMI **Management Class** and it works fine.

More documentation on how to remote start a process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630015/execute-a-process-in-a-remote-machine-using-wmi)

Comment: Actually I included the command option in my answer. Glad you could solve the problem.